# amCharts select property value

Tags: javascript, amcharts

So I have this column chart and I'd like to have the colors based on the category name. To be more clear, my graph is something like this:

```
category 1 [][][][][][]
category 2 [][][][][][][][][][][]
category 3 [][][][]
category 4 [][][][][][][][][]
```

I'm using dataloader to provide data from an ajax request.

I thought of doing something like the following:

```
        "graphs": [{
            "balloonText": "<span style='font-size:13px;'>[[title]] [[category]]s:<b>[[value]]</b></span>",
            "title": "Total",
            "type": "column",
            "fillAlphas": 0.8,
            "fillColors": "color",  <-------------------------
            "valueField": "total"
        }],

if (category.value == "category3") {
  var color = "red"
} ...
```

Well, I guess you got the idea. Thing is, I'm a newbie when it comes to programming and js specially. Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could add "color" to the data objects like this:

```
data = [{"category":"category3","total":"totalValue","color":"red"},...]
```

and in your graph use "fillColorsField" instead of fillColors, like this:

```
"graphs": [{
            "balloonText": "<span style='font-size:13px;'>[[title]] [[category]]s:<b>[[value]]</b></span>",
            "title": "Total",
            "type": "column",
            "fillAlphas": 0.8,
            "fillColorsField": "color",  <-------------------------
            "valueField": "total"
        }],
```

This demo can be usefull: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/column-with-rotated-series/

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply!
But I've seen this example, problem is that I'm using dataloader to get my data, so my data comes from an ajax request, straight from my db. Can I add more info to my aray after the db call, before I send the data to my view?

Comment: I think you can use a for loop and then apend the "color" field to the object. for(var i =0; i<array.length; i++){ if(array[i].category == 'category3')array[i].color = "red";}

Comment: thanks, I'll try that. I'll let you know if it works.